# Laravel 5.3 - Omnipay Paypal Express not returning success message

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3, omnipay, paypal

I'm new to Laravel. I've been struggling to implement Paypal Express Checkout in my website for a couple days in order to enable donations to a non-profit organization. Thanks to [these explanations](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/paypal-on-laravel-5222?page=1) I've been able to install Omnipay, let the user input the amount (s)he wants to donate and go to Paypal.
But, when I try to end the transaction (Pay), I'm not redirected to my succes message. My sandbox account does not show any transactions either, so it seems the payment is not completed correctly. I'm guessing there's something wrong with my "getSuccessPayment" function, but I can't figure out what it is...

Here's my Controller so far :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Omnipay\Omnipay;
use Session;
use App\Http\Requests\PaymentRequest;

class PaymentController extends Controller {

    public function postPayment(PaymentRequest $request)
    {
        $price = $request->get('price');

        $items[] = array('name' => 'Don', 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => $price);

        $params = array(
            'cancelUrl'=>url('/donner'),
            'returnUrl'=>url('/payment_success'),
            'amount' =>  $price,
            'currency' => 'EUR'
        );

        Session::put('params', $params);
        Session::save();

        $gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');
        $gateway->setUsername('my sandbox email'); 
        $gateway->setPassword('my sandbox password');  
        $gateway->setSignature('my sandbox signature');
        $gateway->setTestMode(true);

       $response = $gateway->purchase($params)->setItems($items)->send();

        if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
            print_r($response);
        } elseif ($response->isRedirect()) {
            $response->redirect();
        } else {
            echo $response->getMessage();
        }
    }

     public function getSuccessPayment()
    {

        $gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');
        $gateway->setUsername('my sandbox email'); 
        $gateway->setPassword('my sandbox password');  
        $gateway->setSignature('my sandbox signature');
        $gateway->setTestMode(true);

        $params = Session::get('params');
        $response = $gateway->completePurchase($params)->send();
        $paypalResponse = $response->getData(); 

        if(isset($paypalResponse['PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK']) && $paypalResponse['PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK'] === 'Success') {
            return redirect('/payment_success');

        } else {
            //payment fails
        return redirect('/payment_failure');

        }
    }
}
?>
```

And my Routes :

```
Route::post('donner',
    ['as' => 'payment', 'uses' => 'PaymentController@postPayment']);

Route::get('payment_success', 'PaymentController@getSuccessPayment');

Route::get('payment_failure', 'PaymentController@getSuccessPayment');
```

Comment: Hi @mefimefi thank you for this. I spent whole day trying to do something that they said it was hard to install omnipay/paypal on my version of laravel 5.3.30. I finally managed to crack it today. First in your terminal run: `composer require symfony/event-dispatcher:^2.8`. after that run in terminal: `composer require omnipay/paypal:"2.6.3"`. Of course my version of paypal is the current one (you can also put composer require omnipay/paypal:*). Hope this helps somebody. :)

Comment: I forgot one last one: `composer require ignited/laravel-omnipay:"2.3.0"` and that should do it. After that you need to Service Provider: ` 'Ignited\LaravelOmnipay\LaravelOmnipayServiceProvider',` and Alias: `   'Omnipay'   => 'Ignited\LaravelOmnipay\Facades\OmnipayFacade',` in *config/app.php*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating your gateway parameters you are passing in `/donner` as the `returnUrl`, this is where your users are returned to after completing the PayPal express login and payment confirmation so Laravel would look `Route::get('donner'...` route which you don't have, changing this to `'returnUrl'=>url('/payment_success'),` will bring your users back to your success route and allow you to file the `completePurchase` call.

**Edit for further details based on edited question and comments:**

Customers are returned to your `returnUrl` if the successfully complete the PayPal login and checkout screens, they go to the `cancelUrl` if for whatever reason they quit the process.

In your `PaymentController@getSuccessPayment` method paypal will send back a `token` and `payerID` in the query string (www.example.com/payment_success?token=EC-12345&PayerID=ABC123, omnipay-paypal will automatically pick up on this in the `completePurchase` call which is where you are effective confirming with PayPal that the customer completed the checkout correctly and that the transaction was successful.

To avoid confusion I would rename your current `Route::get('payment_success', 'PaymentController@getSuccessPayment');` route to something like `Route::get('complete_payment', 'PaymentController@getCompletePayment');` and create a new `payment_success` route that a user is sent to after you have confirmed the status of the payment with PayPal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought that returnUrl was only used when a problem occured during payment. My mistake. There's still something I don't get, though: if returnUrl is set as a fixed parameter, how can I know whether the payment was successful? My original intent was to redirect to one url in case of succes (payment_success) and another one in case of failure (payment_failure). How can I achieve that with only one returnUrl?

Comment: @Mefimefi check the edit to my question (long story short; you are already checking if the payment is successful once the customer comes back to you on the ``if(isset($paypalResponse['PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK']) &&...`` line).

Comment: Another tip; Google [prefers](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/76329?hl=en) we use ``-`` instead of ``_`` in URLs, it's worth getting in the habit now!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation - and the additional tip. I finally get how this library works!